# NSScrollView Zooming of subviews

Tags: macos, zooming, nsview, nsscrollview

Apologies for the noob question - coming from an iOS background I'm struggling a little with OSX.

The good news - I have an NSScrollView with a large NSView as it's documentView. I have been adjusting the bounds of the contentView to effectively zoom in on the documentView - and all works well with respect to anything I do in drawRect (of the documentView)

The not so good news - I have now added another NSView as a child of the large documentView and expected it to simply zoom just like it would in iOS land - but it doesn't. If anyone can help fill in the rather large gap in my understanding of all this, I'd be extremely grateful

Thanks.

[UPDATE] Fixed it myself - 'problem' was that autolayout (layout constraints) were enabled. Once I disabled them and set the autosizing appropriately then everything was ok. I guess I should learn about layout constraints...

Comment: I had the same problem but the cause was different, so I thought I'd share it here. My issue was that I had made the document view layer-backed (wantsLayer = true), and changing this fixed the zooming issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old but I just implemented mouse scroll zooming using the following after spending days trying to figure it out using various solutions posted by others, all of which had fundamental issues. As background I and using a CALayers in a NSView subclass with a large PDF building layout in the background and 100+ draggable CALayer objects overplayed on top of that.

The zooming is instant and smooth and everything scales perfectly with no pixellation that I was expecting from something called 'magnification'.  I wasted many days on this.

```
  override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {

        guard event.modifierFlags.contains(.option) else {
            super.scrollWheel(with: event)
            return
        }

        let dy = event.deltaY
        if dy != 0.0 {

            let magnification = self.scrollView.magnification + dy/30
            let point = self.scrollView.contentView.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)

            self.scrollView.setMagnification(magnification, centeredAt: point)
        }
    }
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a scrollWheel function in the iOS scrollView. Was that only on macOS?

Answer (score 0):

LOL, I had exactly the same problem. I lost like two days messing around with autolayout. After I read your update I went in and just added another NSBox to the view and it gets drawn correctly and zooms as well.

Though, does it work for NSImageViews as subviews as well?